# Specificity rules for comma delineated lists

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

When using Cascading Style Sheets I have observed the order of specificity as follows:

**1st Laws**: In-line Styles
**2nd Laws**: Number of ID Selectors
**3rd Laws**: Number of Class Selectors
**4th Laws**: Number of Element Selectors

So, items with in-line styles came first, followed by declarations with one or more ID selectors, followed by declarations with one or more class selectors, followed by declarations with one or more element selectors. With more IDs, classes and elements meaning more precedence, respectively.

From this viewpoint I was unable to comprehend where comma delineated lists of IDs, classes or elements fit. Does a comma delineated list have any special precedence rules? Also, in a single comma delineated list, are IDs, classes and elements considered separate items, for the purposes of calculating specificity?

**Code example**:

```
html, body, header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

What takes precedence in the above example? Is the comma delineated list treated as referencing a single element, in which case the header would take precedence simply for being last in the cascade, or is the comma delineated list treated as multiple elements, and therefore takes precedence? Or are there other rules I should be considering first?

Comment: They are both _exactly the same selector_. You are just combing three separate selectors in to one in your second example. The second would take precedence because it is last and therefore overrules the first.

Comment: 'html, body, header,`would imply that the rules declared would apply to all those selectors specified, and makes no difference in specificity to simply declaring a rule with just the `header` selector - unless of course the rule is lower down in the order of the cascade. So in the example you'e provided above, the second rule for `header` would over-qualify the first rule declared for `header`.

Comment: I noticed there is an error in the above question. I should have placed `html, body, header` at the top instead of the bottom, and altered "Is the comma delineated list treated as referencing a single element, in which case the header would take precedence simply for being first in the cascade, or is the comma delineated list treated as multiple elements, and therefore takes precedence?" to read differently as a result. Should I change it now to rectify my error?

Comment: @Buddha Theis: You should. If nothing else, it makes no difference to the accepted answer.

Comment: I noticed that you were switching accepted answers there. Note that a question can only have one accepted answer at a time, that which answered the question to your satisfaction. Once you have a little more rep you can upvote as many answers as were helpful to you.

Comment: @BoltClock The answer I originally accepted was my favourite one to start with, but when I read yours it had some really interesting bits in so I accepted yours. Then, one of the later parts I got confused and wasn't sure if it was true, or if maybe it didn't quite answer the question I asked in the way I was after, so I went back to the original answer as the accepted one. I am still thinking about all the bits of your one.

Comment: Ah, that's OK, I agree parts of it can be hard to digest. I'd say David's answer sufficiently addresses your example - mine focuses on the other rules you alluded to at the end of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that CSS is cascading - meaning the style that is referenced FURTHER down a CSS file will take precedence assuming the selector is the same:

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
}
p, span, header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  HEADER
</header>
```

If we switch around the declarations above, the opposite happens:

```css
p, span, header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  HEADER
</header>
```

As you can see, comma separated selectors / declaration make no difference - they're treated the same as if you'd done them singly.

Answer (score 8):

> Does a comma delineated list have any special precedence rules?

Strictly speaking, a selector-list does not have its own specificity value, but for the purposes of the cascade, the specificity of a selector-list is equal to the specificity of the most specific selector that matches the element. This is not stated explicitly in [the current specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors), but it appears in [selectors-4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#specificity-rules). Even so, since a selector-list is nothing more than a way to combine two or more selectors in a single expression without having to repeat their style declarations, it makes sense why it would work this way.

Remember that a selector is only relevant to an element when it matches the element — otherwise, it never enters into specificity calculations, or any part of the cascade.

> Also, in a single comma delineated list, are IDs, classes and elements considered separate items, for the purposes of calculating specificity?

Every simple selector has its own specificity value, but these values are added up at the complex-selector level. A complex selector is one part of a selector-list. For example, the selector-list

```
.foo > .bar, nav input:checked + label
```

has two complex selectors:

1. `.foo > .bar`, with a specificity of (0, 2, 0)
2. `nav input:checked + label`, with a specificity of (0, 1, 3)

> What takes precedence in the above example? Is the comma delineated list treated as referencing a single element, in which case the header would take precedence simply for being last in the cascade, or is the comma delineated list treated as multiple elements, and therefore takes precedence?

In your example, the selector-list `html, body, header` consists of three separate lone type selectors. Since every element can only be of one element type at a time, it's easy to deduce that all three selectors in the list are mutually exclusive, i.e. an element can only match one of any of the three selectors at a time (or none at all). A `header` element can never match the `html` or `body` selectors, and so neither of those selectors is relevant. You just have the `header` selector to deal with, and specificity becomes less of an issue in your example. The result is that your *second* rule, with just the `header` selector, takes precedence, because the only two selectors that are relevant are equally specific.

But this becomes more pertinent when you have a selector-list that consists of more than one selector that can match the same element. Let's pretend that both selectors in my example above can match the same `label` element. So we have two selectors of specificity (0, 2, 0) and (0, 1, 3) that both match the same element. As in the first paragraph of my answer, the specificity is equal to that of the most specific selector, (0, 2, 0). It is *not*, as one might otherwise have guessed, the total specificity of *all* matching selectors (0, 3, 3), or the specificity of the least specific (which wouldn't really make sense anyway).

This means, for example, that a separate rule with a selector whose specificity is (0, 3, 0) will still take precedence over the selector-list, *even if both selectors in that list match the same element*. Consider this contrived example (you'll *rarely* find examples of this in the wild):

```css
.foo > .bar.baz {
  color: red;
}

.foo > .bar, nav input:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
  <label for="check" class="bar baz">Checkbox</label>
</nav>
```

Notice that regardless of whether the checkbox is checked, the `label` *never* turns blue. This is because `.foo > .bar.baz` has a specificity of (0, 3, 0) which is higher than each of the two individual specificities given above, even though it's lower than the combined specificity, since specificities are never combined this way.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS separating rules by `,` means listing multiple selectors. So `html, body, header` style will be applied to every `html`, `body` and `header` no matter if some of it is missing or not. It will not provide any precedence to selector.

In your example `header` position will be absolute just because first rule will have lower precedence than second. Same as:

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this case both of them are Element Selectors so the outputted css would be bottom one because css is rendered from top to bottom precedence in this case takes last element.