# CSS: selector with lower specificity overrides selector with higher specificity

Tags: css

A HTML tag has the properties bellow:

[image]
[image]

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743715/specificity-rules-for-comma-delineated-lists) question's answer it's written that

> comma separated selectors / declaration make no difference - they're treated the same as if you'd done them singly.

Shouldn't the font-size of the `.main_hero__message` selector be more specific, and thus have priority over the `h1` selector's font_size ?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] please?

Comment: did you tried rem for .main_hero__message too?

Comment: I tried. But I can't reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: It means "relative em"; it's a measurement unit of font size.

Comment: @DavidB. It could be that `_type.scss` comes after the `style` tag, thus having more priority!

Comment: am pretty sure that class is the class of a container and not of the h1

Comment: I also tried to add use `rem` in `.main_hero__message`. It doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @NarenMurali order doesn't matter here since both don't have the same specificity

Comment: @NarenMurali it would have priority if they had the same level of specificity. But `.main_hero__message` has higher specificity and should have priority. Isn't that so ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right. It was the container.

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, verifiable example, as requested in the first comment.

Comment: your <style> tag is before your <link> in your head, that is why i guess.

Comment: so we no more have specificity issue then ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh ok, got it, Thanks :)